# Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps and asynchronous suspension

Tags: flutter, dart

```
httpErrorHandle(
        response: res, 
        context: context,
        onSuccess: () async {
          SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
          Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false).setUser(res.body);
          await prefs.setString('x-auth-token', jsonDecode(res.body)['token']);
          Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
            context, 
            BottomBar.routeName, 
            (route) => false,
            );
        },
      );
```

I have a problem in this part of the code. This is not an error but it is an annoying warning. I also got an error  and I have no clue how to resolve this. I can't use mounted property because this is not a stateful widget, this is a void function signInUser..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It is a warning message, you can use `mounted` to check whether the current state obj is on widget tree.

```dart
await prefs.setString(....);
if(mounted) {   
  Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(...);
 }
```

For `StatelessWidget` you can use context like

```dart
if(context.mounted){
  
}
```

Comment: Yes but I can't use mounted because this is a void function, not a stateful widget..

Comment: use `context.mounted`

Comment: I tried and got an error: "The getter 'mounted' isn't defined for the type 'BuildContext'.
Try importing the library that defines 'mounted', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'mounted'."

Comment: can you try to upgrade the flutter, if it is not

Comment: it was on the latest version. I started the application, did absolutely nothing and it opened correctly after 7 days of not working properly. Now I am even more confused but also happy haha

Comment: sorry this is all my understanding based on current context

Comment: All fine! Thank you anyways. :)